# How to loop outwards from a point in an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, algorithm, loops

I have the following array:

```
let arr = [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,
            6,  7,  8,  9, 10,
           11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
           16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
           21, 22, 23, 24, 25 ]
```

How will I write a function, which will loop through the elements adjacent to it. For example, if I input 13, it will go through 7,8,9,12,14,17,18 and 19 and then the elements adjacent to them i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,15,16,20,21,22,23 and 25.

I have tried looping separately. that is +5,-5,+6,-6,+4,-4,+1 and -1. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to make it work.

Also, if any of the inputs are corner then the rest of the elements will be looped through. For example, if 1 is given then 2,6 and 7 and then 3,8,13,12,11 and so on. In essence all elements should be looped through.

Comment: What's your precise definition of "adjacency"? When you picked 13 as example, I understand 12 and 14 to be adjacent in the normal sense of the word, but then you say 7,8,9,17,18.19 are adjacent to 13 but not 11 or 15?

Comment: Will the array always have 25 numbers or any n^2 numbers?

Comment: @lurker by adjacency I mean, all the elements next to it. If I were to put the array as a grid.

Comment: It can contain any n^2 numbers

Comment: Will the array always have natural numbers? If 13 is given, it can be assumed that it will be at index = 12?

Comment: Yes it will always contain natural numbers sorted in ascending order. And yes it will be at index 12

Comment: So the assumption is that the number of elements in your array is a perfect square?

Comment: yes it is a perfect aquare always

Comment: The problem may be easier and the logic clearer if you put them into a 2D array.

Comment: So the input is just the value of n, and a value to start with.

Comment: @trincot the answer to that is yes

Comment: You received several answers... Any feed-back to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the size of the array and row & column of the current number. Then get all indexes from `[row-1,col-1]` to `[row+1,col+1]`. Some of the values could be negative for border elements. So, exclude those

```js
function surronding(array, n) {
  const size = Math.sqrt(array.length),
        index = n - 1,
        row = Math.floor(index / size),
        col = index % size,
        output = []

  for (let x = row - 1; x <= row + 1; x++) {
    for (let y = col - 1; y <= col + 1; y++) {
    
      if (x === row && y === col) // current
        continue;

      if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= size || y >= size) // out of range
        continue;

      output.push(arr[x * size + y])
    }
  }
  
  return output;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]

console.log(...surronding(arr, 13))
console.log(...surronding(arr, 1))
console.log(...surronding(arr, 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to do a bucket sort of the values, where there is a bucket for each possible distance of the value to the given "center" value, and then output the buckets in order of distance:

```js
function solve(n, root) {
    const x = --root % n;
    const y = (root - x) / n;
    const result = Array.from({length: n}, () => []);
    for (let i = 0; i < n*n; i++) {
        if (i == root) continue; 
        result[Math.max(Math.abs(x - i % n), Math.abs(y - Math.floor(i / n)))].push(i+1);
    }
    return result.flat();
}

console.log(solve(5, 13));
```

Comment: This is nice and simple.  I wrote my own version before seeing this, and won't bother posting it now that I've seen this answer.  Mine did the same calculations, but inside a `sort` call, which would grow much more quickly than this version.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to transpose your value to line, column position.

```js
const arr =
  [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,
    6,  7,  8,  9, 10,
    11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
    16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
    21, 22, 23, 24, 25 ]

function getAdjacents(number, arr)
  {
  let sQ = Math.sqrt(arr.length)
    , n  = number -1     // first position is zero 
    , C_ = n % sQ        // column position
    , R_ = (n - C_) / sQ // row position
    ;
  return Array(3).fill().reduce((z,_,r)=>
          [...z,...Array(3).fill().map((_,c)=>[r+R_-1,c+C_-1])],[])
          .reduce((res,[rx,cx])=>
            {
            if ( rx>=0  && cx>=0 
             &&  rx<sQ  && cx<sQ 
             && (rx!=R_ || cx!=C_) ) 
              res.push((rx*sQ)+cx+1)
            return res
            },[])
  }

console.log(13, '->', ...getAdjacents(13, arr) )  //-> 7 8 9 12 14 17 18 19 
console.log( 1, '->', ...getAdjacents( 1, arr) )  //-> 2 6 7
console.log( 5, '->', ...getAdjacents( 5, arr) )  //-> 4 9 10
console.log(22, '->', ...getAdjacents(22, arr) )  //-> 16 17 18 21 23
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an approach with the length of the sides and an offset for the pivot element. as result, you get an index for a linear array.

```js
const getAdjacent = (length, startI, startJ, offset = 0) => {
    const indices = [];
    offset++;
    for (let i = startI - offset; i <= startI + offset; i++) {
        for (let j = startJ - offset; j <= startJ + offset; j++) {
            if (
                i < 0 || i >= length || j < 0 || j >= length ||
                (i !== startI - offset && i !== startI + offset && j !== startJ - offset && j !== startJ + offset)
            ) continue;
            indices.push(i * length + j);
        }
    }
    return indices;
};

console.log(...getAdjacent(5, 2, 2, 0));
console.log(...getAdjacent(5, 2, 2, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this fundamentally works the same way as @trincot's answer but I already had written most of it, hopefully it's okay to still post it.

```js
const row_col_for_number = (square_side_size, number) => [
  parseInt((number - 1) / square_side_size) + 1,
  ((number - 1) % square_side_size) + 1
];

const biggest_row_col_diff = ([a_row, a_col], [b_row, b_col]) =>
  Math.max(Math.abs(a_row - b_row), Math.abs(a_col - b_col));

const distance_to_start = (square_side_size, start_row_col, number) =>
  biggest_row_col_diff(
    start_row_col,
    row_col_for_number(square_side_size, number)
  );

const sort_square_adjacency = (square_side_size, start_row_col) => (a, b) =>
  distance_to_start(square_side_size, start_row_col, a) -
  distance_to_start(square_side_size, start_row_col, b);

const doit = (square_side_size, start_number) =>
  new Array(square_side_size * square_side_size)
    .fill(0)
    .map((_, i) => i + 1)
    .sort(
      sort_square_adjacency(
        square_side_size,
        row_col_for_number(square_side_size, start_number)
      )
    )
    .slice(1);

console.log(...doit(5, 1));
console.log(...doit(5, 13));
```